# Remove multiple XML declarations in XML

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, serialization, xml-serialization

The app should add the nodes from time to time to `Goals.xml` file. So its `dynamic`. The code that adds the nodes:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings=new XmlWriterSettings();  
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration= true;
settings.Indent = true;
settings.IndentChars = ("\t");

using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = 
    IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = 
    myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Goals.xml", FileMode.Append))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Goals>));
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(
            xmlWriter, 
            GenerateGoalsData(name, description, progress));
    }
}
```

and

```
private List<Goals> GenerateGoalsData(
    string name, 
    string description, 
    string progress)
{
    List<Goals> data = new List<Goals>();
    data.Add(new Goals() { 
            Name=name, 
            Description=description, 
            Progress=progress});
    return data;
}
```

and also I have class `Goals`. But it generates bad `XML`:

```
<ArrayOfGoals xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Goals>
        <Name>Jack</Name>
        <Description>lalala</Description>
        <Progress>97</Progress>
    </Goals>
</ArrayOfGoals>
<ArrayOfGoals xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Goals>
        <Name>Taaaaaa</Name>
        <Description>nanana</Description>
        <Progress>50</Progress>
    </Goals>
</ArrayOfGoals>
```

How to remove in `XML` the repeated:

```
</ArrayOfGoals>
<ArrayOfGoals xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

so the `XML` looks like that:

```
<ArrayOfGoals xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Goals>
        <Name>Jack</Name>
        <Description>lalala</Description>
        <Progress>97</Progress>
    </Goals>
    <Goals>
        <Name>Taaaaaa</Name>
        <Description>nanana</Description>
        <Progress>50</Progress>
    </Goals>
</ArrayOfGoals>
```

Or how to append the nodes without that string being automatically added?

Answer (score 2):

Deserialize your data, add new values and serialize. But
Use `FileMode.Create`  instead of `FileMode.Append`

Comment: +1. Read-add-save is safe approach. Added another answer if OP wants to keep appending data.

Comment: So and how to append new nodes to deserialized xml. Im stacked after                                               XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Goals>));
List<Goals> data = (List<Goals>)serializer.Deserialize(stream); how to work with this variable data?

Comment: @AntonMashikhin `how to append new nodes to deserialized xml`. No need  for xml processing. After deserialization, you have your `data`. Add new goals to `data` and serialize it

Answer (score 2):

The resulting file is invalid XML, so you will not be able to use it directly for deserialization as valid Xml.

But it is actually valid "Xml fragments" which can be read with standard classes: XmlReader can read fragments when specifying ConformanceLevel.Frament in XmlReaderSettings of XmlReader.Create call.  I think you'll be even able to deserialize classes directly from such reader (not sure).

Side note: it would be much easier (but less problems and bugs) to read old data, append what you need and serialize back as whole file.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute("Goals");     
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Goals>), root);
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);   
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
{
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, GenerateGoalsData(name, description, progress), ns)
}
```